# RxJS forkJoin handle error on route resolve

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, fork-join

I can't seem to figure out a way to catch/handle errors inside forkJoin while trying to do route resolve.

I've created a route resolver for Account page and It should return 2 requests before routing. Now here is the part I cant work out: If user doesn't have a subscription then 404 is returned from server. I would like to handle this and if it happens, user should be routed to a different page, from where he could make subscription.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Resolve, ActivatedRouteSnapshot } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import { AccountService } from './account.service';

@Injectable()
export class AccountResolver implements Resolve<any> {
    constructor(private accountService: AccountService) { }

    resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): Observable<any> {
        return Observable.forkJoin([
            this.accountService.getUser(),
            this.accountService.getUserSubscriptions()
        ]);
    };
}
```

How do I catch and handle error 404 sent by server when getUserSubscriptions() is requested?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can catch the error, and redirect to desired route as follows:

```
@Injectable()
export class AccountResolver implements Resolve<any> {
    constructor(private accountService: AccountService,
                private router: Router) { }

    resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): Observable<any> {
        return Observable.forkJoin([
            this.accountService.getUser(),
            this.accountService.getUserSubscriptions()
                .catch(error => {
                    if(error.status === 404) {
                        this.router.navigate(['subscription-create']);
                    }

                    return Observable.throw(error);
                })
        ]);
    };
}
```

This way, the error is handled, but also returned to the `resolve` method in its original shape, so the resolver can reject access to the previously targeted route (any failed request within the `forkJoin` will lead to failing the `forkJoin` itself by default).

Comment: Allready tried it and it didn't help. I got this error: 
Argument of type '(error: any) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(err: any, caught: Observable<UserSubscription>) => ObservableInput<UserSubscription, {}>'.
  Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'ObservableInput<UserSubscription, {}>'.

Comment: My problem here was that I didn't know that inside catch I would have to do return. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5):

This depends where the error happens which is not entire obvious from your example.

If the `getUserSubscriptions()` call emits an error then you need to catch it before passing this to `forkJoin` because otherview the `forkJoin` will reemit the error. Also note that `forkJoin` requires each source Observable to emit at least one value. This is why I can't use `Observable.empty()` and I need to use for example `Observable.of(null)`.

```
return Observable.forkJoin([
    this.accountService.getUser(),
    this.accountService.getUserSubscriptions()
        .catch(err => {
            // Logic based on the err parameter
            return Observable.of(null);
        })
]);
```

This will just replace the error with `null` so you can handle it in the subscriber to the `forkJoin`.

Comment: Just wondering, why would he catch the error and return the Observable instead? The point isn't to successfully resolve route dependencies, but inspect the 404 error and redirect accordingly..